# mkdir() not working with URL

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I can create a directory at C:/xamp/https/Hospital_DB but
I want to create a directory like this http://localhost:8800/Hospital_DB/

My code currrently looks like

```
$loc="http://localhost:8800/Hospital_DB/";

$img_location=$loc."scan".date("/Y/n/d/");

if (!file_exists($img_location)) 
{
  mkdir($img_location, 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a web address as the pathname with `mkdir()`, you must use your server's driectory structure. For example;

```
mkdir('/path/to/www/Hospital_DB/', 0777, true);
```

If you don't know what it is, you can try a [magic constant](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) like `__DIR__` to get it.